# AJAX: head and more

Tags: javascript, ajax, http

For asynchronous quick-checks of an URL, I use AJAX with method=HEAD:

```
function ajax_quickresponse(url) {
    var xmlhttp = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject)
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if (xmlhttp) {
        xmlhttp.open("HEAD", url, true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if ((xmlhttp.status > 199 && xmlhttp.status < 400))
                    ; //OK
                else
                    ; //ERR
            };
        };
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    };
};
```

This receives is enough for checking the http status, but seems to abort the script at serverside (url). E.g. I can try with a simple php script (url="http://my-host.er/test/script.php") which does sleep(2); and log a success message afterwards.
With `xmlhttp.open("HEAD", url, true);`, there is no success entry in the log.

With `xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);`, there is a success entry in the log.

However, with GET/POST, the javascript is waiting 2 seconds instead of instantly (with HEAD).

The status is known instantly and the javascript does not need to wait for the final response.

How to take advantage of both methods? First, I need the status instantly, as soon as the header comes in, and after the external url/script returns, then i'd like another listener.

E.g. first `alert('http status='+xmlhttp.status);` and maybe delayed, depending on the url/script,  `alert('finally completed');`

Do you have a tip how to achieve this with one single call?